# How can I enable preserving of the run dialog box history in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, command-history

On my PC (Windows XP), the "Run" dialog box does not keep the history of previous commands till the next time my computer is restarted! So no suggestions are shown when a command is entered after reboot.

How do I enable this?

Answer (score 0):

One option you can try is to check (and possibly set) this registry value:

Key *ClearRecentDocsOnExit* in path:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER \ Software \ Microsoft \ Windows\ CurrentVersion \ Policies \ Explorer

When set to '1', the run history should not get cleared.

[[source]](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/runmru.htm)

Comment: i checked that path in regedit but that value is set on 1 before